# File response from api to img tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using an api which sends a QR code as a file. I want to be able to use it in nodejs.

I have to send it as an html file to another api. It is a png file and it shows like this in postman raw.

```
IHDRyyh
��IDATx�����0D7K�����V#�
�yǤ ~�����|������ceV&`e����q���>����<���V&T~�����#��(����Xe+*'�5ɟ��hQ��T*c�leV&`eV& =}U�<v���   �����Zէ}ձ�U�2�r_=���7�����U�2��unJw�i$��V&TN�}�?-��}�zv���  ���{uV>��K%�U�2����R#�{z�v�� {Xe+*K���w��;W>8�ӗ��[[�j�D�,��G0V���ʭ�V�{_��l+�5V�����w������-z�be@��;NDg����^�?�*[�Py��=k��&���V&T�����p�������   ��81Q��jn�G���  ��8���\%��*[�P��;NL�'�����1����w���*[���    X��_���>���0V�IEND�B`�
```

I tried doing something like this but didn't work

```
<img
    src="data:image/png;base64,�PNG  IHDRyyh ��IDATx�����0D7K�����V#� �yǤ   ~�����|������ceV&`e����q���>����<���V&T~�����#��(����Xe+*'�5ɟ��hQ��T*c�leV&`eV& =}U�<v���   �����Zէ}ձ�U�2�r_=���7�����U�2��unJw�i$��V&TN�}�?-��}�zv���  ���{uV>��K%�U�2����R#�{z�v�� {Xe+*K���w��;W>8�ӗ��[[�j�D�,��G0V���ʭ�V�{_��l+�5V�����w������-z�be@��;NDg����^�?�*[�Py��=k��&���V&T�����p�������   ��81Q��jn�G���  ��8���\%��*[�P��;NL�'�����1����w���*[���    X��_���>���0V�IEND�B`�"
    alt="">
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the data you have is NOT base64 encoded - it appears to probably just be binary.  If you want to use it in a `data:` URL, it must be properly encoded.

Comment: Okay, how do I use it in binary?

Comment: If you want to put it in a `data:` URL, then you encode it as base64.  How exactly you do that depends upon what form the original binary data is in.  If you can show that code, we can advise more specifically.  For example, if the data is in a Buffer object in nodejs, you can use `let encodedString = buf.toString('base64')` to encode it and then put that encoded string into the `data` URL.